# gcc not working on mac

Tags: c, macos, gcc

I have **updated to Xcode to v4.2.1 from v3** and it works fine but as a C newbie I want to code in Text Wrangler and compile with gcc in the CLI.

gcc returns 'command not found' for some reason now (it worked fine earlier)

After some googling I figured out **gcc was moved to /Developer/usr/bin from /usr/bin** (I can see it there).
Now gcc runs when I use the exact path but it **can't find any of the header files.**

```
my-MacBook-Pro:Desktop user$ /Developer/usr/bin/gcc -o program  program.c 
program.c:15:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
program.c:16:18: error: math.h: No such file or directory
program.c:17:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
program.c: In function ‘main’:
program.c:33: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
program.c:35: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘sqrt’
program.c:44: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
program.c:65: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Xcode 4.3+ the 'Command Line Tools' package is not installed by default. You can download it in Preferences -> Downloads. Note that you need Lion.

EDIT:

In Xcode < 4.3 the Command Line Tools is included in the Xcode install, so the above solution doesn't apply.

However, try using xcode-select: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html

EDIT 2:
Install Command Line Tools for Xcode from the downloads section on the [Apple dev site.](http://developer.apple.com)

Comment: this is not quite true @Butaca... Xcode 4.3 is what took away the /Developer directory and brought in the "Command Line Tools" installer packages.

Comment: Ok. No Xcode folder was set. I set it to /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app. Now, : `user$ xcode-select -print-path && xcodebuild -version /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app
Error: Can't run /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/usr/bin`/xcodebuild (no such file).'

Comment: In my computer with Snow Leopard and Xcode 4.2, xcodebuild is in /Developer/usr/bin. Maybe you should point to /Developer/ instead of /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app

Comment: Its working, thanks! Installed Command Line Tools for Xcode from the Dev site. gcc is in /usr/bin now. Although now I have another copy lying around in /Developer/usr/bin